# How do I set a Port to Ground using Vivado's I/O Planning tool

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vivado

So, I've designed a 2-bit Full Adder, made up of Full Adders and Half Adders. I just started using Vivado's I/O Planning tool for the port to pin assignments, but I've run into a problem. One of my inputs, the initial carry_in for the first bit, I want set to ground since it should always be 0. I know I could just force it to 0 in my VHDL code, but I'm told that's not really the proper way to do it. I tried to set that port to one of the ground pins in the i/o planner but Vivado just tells me I can't place a terminal in an empty pin location. Anyone know how to do this?

As a temporary solution, I just assigned the carry_in port to a button input that I'll leave unpressed so it will always be 0. Everything works as it should when it's programmed onto the board.

*Using Vivado 2015.2 and working on the ZYBO Development Board.

Here's the top level 2-bit Full Adder Code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;

entity full_adder_2bit is
     port(
         a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
         b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
         carry_in : in STD_LOGIC;
         sum : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0);
         carry_out : out STD_LOGIC
         );
end full_adder_2bit;

architecture structural of full_adder_2bit is

component full_adder is
     port(
         a : in STD_LOGIC;
         b : in STD_LOGIC;
         carry_in : in STD_LOGIC;
         sum : out STD_LOGIC;
         carry_out : out STD_LOGIC
         );
end component;

signal cin_fa1 : std_logic;

begin

    fa0: full_adder port map (a => a(0), b => b(0), carry_in => carry_in, sum => sum(0), carry_out => cin_fa1); 

    fa1: full_adder port map (a => a(1), b => b(1), carry_in => cin_fa1, sum => sum(1), carry_out => carry_out);

end structural;
```

And here's what I've got for constraints from the I/O planner. It all works fine, I just want to set the carry_in to ground instead of an unused button.

```
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {a[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {a[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {b[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {b[0]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sum[1]}]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports {sum[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN T16 [get_ports {a[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN P15 [get_ports {a[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN W13 [get_ports {b[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN G15 [get_ports {b[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN M15 [get_ports {sum[1]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN M14 [get_ports {sum[0]}]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN D18 [get_ports carry_out]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports carry_out]
set_property PACKAGE_PIN Y16 [get_ports carry_in]
set_property IOSTANDARD LVCMOS33 [get_ports carry_in]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could assign it to an unused, unconnected pin and put activate the internal pulldown on it.

However, it's better to tie it to `'0'` in your VHDL file. The comment "it's not the proper way to do it" is somewhat debatable. A full adder entity should really have the carry_in input. However, a FPGA toplevel should really only have the pins it requires.

The better way to do it would be to have a file (let's say, toplevel.vhd) that instantiates a full_adder_2bit tying the carry-in to `'0'`. That way, full_adder_2bit keeps it useful carry_in bit and your toplevel is rid of unecessary pin.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I like that idea of having a seperate toplevel vhdl file that instantiates a 2bit full adder, that way I don't interfere with the carry_in in the 2bit full adder. I'll give that a try.

Comment: Is is good to enable an additional pulldown in the FPGA? If the user uses `Y16` on the ZYBO, there is already a 10k pulldown and a 10k series resistor on net `BTN3`. [ZYBO schematic](http://digilentinc.com/Data/Products/ZYBO/ZYBO_sch_VB.3.pdf#page=2)

Comment: @Paebbels Putting an internal pulldown on a pin that has an external pullup/pulldown is harmless. It is equivalent to teo resistors in parallel/series and would only cause more current flow than desired, and potentially unstable input reading if the tension is not above/below threshold. I said to use an unconnected pin, which in my mind was a floating pin...